# Is the "who" clause restrictive or nonrestrictive in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, restrictive-clauses

Could you please tell me if I should insert a comma before who in this sentence that I've written? I feel that the "who" is nonrestrictive here since the clause "who hadn't wanted kids" is not required to identify the "boyfriend of twenty years." Am I right?

Jane had gone to adopt a child after breaking up with her boyfriend of twenty years who hadn't wanted kids.

Comment: The information in the relative clause is an integral part of the larger message, so there's no reason to treat it as a supplementary (non-restrictive) relative.

Comment: @BillJ Hmm ... treating it as a restrictive implies that Jane had at least two boyfriends of twenty years :)

Comment: @StoneyB There are times when relatives that in theory are supplementary seem distinctly odd when analysed that way. Does this look OK to you?: "Jane had gone to adopt a child after breaking up with her boyfriend of twenty years, who hadn't wanted kids" I don't think so.

Comment: @BillJ Indeed I do prefer the clause bracketed: as the sentence stands the relative is not an identification of the boyfriend but a comment explaining the connection between the adoption in the main clause and the breakup in the first subordinate clause.

Comment: @StoneyB It reminds me of the appositive "This is my wife Lucy". There is no implication here that I have more than one wife; rather, the integrated construction simply provides a succinct way of saying that the person concerned is my wife and is named Lucy. I'd apply the same logic to the OP's example.

Comment: @BillJ I'll concede that it's an edge case; I'm influenced in my reading by the position of the relative, which opens the door to understanding it as an afterthought, and by the determinacy of the noun phrase: I'd have no difficulty with ***a** boyfriend of twenty years who didn't want kids*.

Comment: @StoneyB The point is that some relatives (and appositives) can be integrated though not semantically restrictive, as my example and the OP's demonstrates. The rationale behind H&P's use of the terms 'integrated' and 'supplementary' rather than 'restrictive' and 'non-restrictive' is nicely demonstrated here.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I agree that 'non-restrictive' and 'supplemental* are not quite isomorphic; and I'd also say that 'supplemental' vs 'integrated' may be a matter of information packaging rather than syntax *sensu stricto*.